# Trying to manipulate javascript error messages with HTTP requests

Tags: javascript, http, security, xss

I was trying to test an admin panel service to find vulnerabilities for security purposes.

By intercepting my requests in Burp Suite, i found out the web page redirects you a bunch of times before dropping you off at the panel login page.
In between the redirects, i found some `try {} catch () {}` blocks in the javascript of one of the html pages.
If there is an error the page will replace the `.innerHTML` of an element with something like the following:

```
"ERROR: parent.window.location.href: " + err.message + "</ br>"
```

Is there any chance for me to manipulate the error message and find an XSS vulnerablity?

Please note that I am performing these actions in a virtual environment with the admin panel running on my own machine.

Comment: Assigning to `.innerHTML` doesn't run scripts. But you could create an element with an `onclick` attribute that does something, then when you click on it you can get XSS.

Comment: @Barmar yes, i was thinking of putting in an <img> element with an onError attribute to execute javascript.

Comment: I was struggling to think of an event handler that will run without user interaction, but I think that will do it.

Comment: @Barmar yes, just need to find a way to change err.message

Comment: Something like ```throw '<img src="nonexistent" onerror="alert(\'foo\')">';` ```

Comment: @Barmar yes i was thinking exactly that